# How can I make the <li> expand so its `padding-right` takes effect?

Tags: html, css

I have a basic tree structure. The container is scrollable horizontally. I have right padding on all `<li>` elements. However, the right padding is not taking effect. How can I fix it so it takes effect?

```css
ul {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

div {
  width: 150px;
  background: white;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

li {
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding-right: 25px;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: coral;
  font-family: apple-sytem,BlinkMacSystemFont,sans-serif;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            Thing
        </li>
        <li style="padding-left: 25px;">
            Another thing
        </li>
        <li style="padding-left: 50px;">
            A really long thing
        </li>
        <li style="padding-left: 75px;">
            An even longer thing
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[Live JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/colmtuite/whspe6ux/3/)

Comment: try removing white-space: nowrap

Comment: That works but I need `white-space: nowrap` to prevent the text from wrapping. I tried adding a `span` inside the `<li>` and moving it to that, but the same issue occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `display: inline-block` to the `<li>` element and it will work.